# Where's the htaccess file in codeigniter?

Tags: apache, codeigniter-url

I'm wondering how CodeIgniter rewrites the url. By default, there is no htaccess file, yet
it still works?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's been some time but in case you don't know .htaccess is a hidden file and it lies on your root folder...
hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Everything is routed through index.php.  i.e.

```
  site.com/index.php/controller/method/arg
```

You'd use an htaccess file to remove the "index.php" slice of the URL. i.e.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/assets|/tmp|/robots\.txt|/crossdomain\.xml|/favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Which would give you "prettier" URLs, i.e.

```
  site.com/controller/method/arg
```

But, this is not necessary for CI to route URLs correctly. Depending on your apache conf, this typically will still resolve correctly, and handoff the request to index.php, which in turn determines the "path" to be /controller/method/arg.